# How to create all non-isomorphic trees with n=6 nodes?

Tags: r, tree, igraph

I need to create all non-isomorphic trees with n=6 nodes. I have found the degree sequence and try to generate trees this degree.sequence.game() function:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(46)
par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
degs <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,
                 1,1,1,3,2,2,
                 1,1,2,2,2,2, 
                 1,1,1,1,2,4,
                 1,1,1,1,1,5,
                 1,1,1,1,3,3), nrow=6, byrow=T) 
for(i in 1:6){
g6 <- degree.sequence.game(degs[i,], method="vl")
plot(g6, vertex.label=NA)
}
```

The output is:

[image]

One can see graphs A and B in left figure are isomorphic.
Expected result in right figure.

**Question.** What is an alternative method to create non-isomorphic trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

It seems I misunderstood your objective. Below might be one solution if you try `simple.no.multiple.uniform` option with in `degree.sequence.game`, i.e.,

```
g6 <- degree.sequence.game(degs[i, ], method = "simple.no.multiple.uniform")
```

and we can obtain

[image]

BTW, the version of `igraph` I am using is `igraph_1.3.5` (you can see it when typing `sessionInfo()` in the console) and you can try with this version, which hopefully helps to address your problem as well.

---

## Previous Answer

I think the pain point in your problem is ***"How to find all distinct degree sequences with given number of vertices in a tree graph?"***.

---

We can break this primary problem into two sub-problems:

1. What is the sum of degrees given `n` vertices (if we want generate a tree)? The answer is: `2*(n-1)`
2. How to partition the `2*(n-1)` into `n` non-isomorphic groups that consist of positive integers? the answer is: Using `partitions::restrictedparts`

```
library(partitions)
n <- 6
degs <- t(restrictedparts(2*(n-1), n, include.zero = FALSE)
```

and you will see

```
> degs

[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 5
[2,] 1 1 1 1 2 4
[3,] 1 1 1 1 3 3
[4,] 1 1 1 2 2 3
[5,] 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

then you can use `degree.sequence.game(degs[i,], method="vl")` by iterating `i` through `1` to `nrow(degs)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My problem is degree sequences. But how to be with 6th tree? The trees with deg(1,1,1,3,2,2) and deg(1,1,1,2,2,3) are non-isomorphic.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for you feedback and now I see your point. Pls check with my latest solution.